# Python: convert 'days since 1990' to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

I have a time series that I have pulled from a netCDF file and I'm trying to convert them to a datetime format. The format of the time series is in 'days since 1990-01-01 00:00:00 +10' (+10 being GMT: +10)

```
time = nc_data.variables['time'][:]
time_idx = 0  # first timestamp 
print time[time_idx]

9465.0
```

My desired output is a datetime object like so (also GMT +10):

```
"2015-12-01 00:00:00"
```

I have tried converting this using the time module without much success although I believe I may be using wrong (I'm still a novice in python and programming).

```
import time
time_datetime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(time[time_idx]*24*60*60))
```

Any advice appreciated,
Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `datetime` module's [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) is probably what you're looking for.

For example:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

days = 9465                 # This may work for floats in general, but using integers
                            #   is more precise (e.g. days = int(9465.0))

start = date(1990,1,1)      # This is the "days since" part

delta = timedelta(days)     # Create a time delta object from the number of days

offset = start + delta      # Add the specified number of days to 1990

print(offset)               # >>>  2015-12-01
print(type(offset))         # >>>  <class 'datetime.date'>
```

You can then use and/or manipulate the offset object, or convert it to a string representation however you see fit.

You can use the same format as for this date object as you do for your `time_datetime`:

```
print(offset.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
2015-12-01 00:00:00
```

---

Instead of using a `date` object, you could use a `datetime` object instead if, for example, you were later going to add hours/minutes/seconds/timezone offsets to it.

The code would stay the same as above with the exception of two lines:

```
# Here, you're importing datetime instead of date
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Here, you're creating a datetime object instead of a date object
start = datetime(1990,1,1)   # This is the "days since" part
```

**Note:** Although you don't state it, but the other answer suggests you might be looking for *timezone aware* datetimes.  If that's the case, `dateutil` is the way to go in Python 2 as the other answer suggests.  In Python 3, you'd want to use the `datetime` module's [`tzinfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer! The datetime object is preferred as there are timestamps for each hour of December.

Comment: Great happy it helped -- and happy I included that then :)

Answer (score 10):

[netCDF num2date](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/#netCDF4.num2date) is the correct function to use here:

```
import netCDF4

ncfile = netCDF4.Dataset('./foo.nc', 'r')
time = ncfile.variables['time'] # do not cast to numpy array yet 
time_convert = netCDF4.num2date(time[:], time.units, time.calendar)
```

This will convert number of days since 1900-01-01 (i.e. the `units` of `time`) to python datetime objects.  If `time` does not have a `calendar` attribute, you'll need to specify the calendar, or use the default of standard.

Answer (score 4):

We can do this in a couple steps. First, we are going to use the [`dateutil`](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) library to handle our work. It will make some of this easier.

The first step is to get a `datetime` object from your string (`1990-01-01 00:00:00 +10`). We'll do that with the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import dateutil.parser

days_since = '1990-01-01 00:00:00 +10'
days_since_dt = dateutil.parser.parse(days_since)
```

Now, our `days_since_dt` will look like this:

```
datetime.datetime(1990, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 36000))
```

We'll use that in our next step, of determining the new date. We'll use `relativedelta` in dateutils to handle this math.

```
new_date = days_since_dt + relativedelta(days=9465.0)
```

This will result in your value in `new_date` having a value of:

```
datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, 36000))
```

---

This method ensures that the answer you receive continues to be in GMT+10.

Comment: Thanks Andy, the dateutil library is a great tool I was unaware of.